# Developing reporting engine in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reporting-services, reporting

this may be a little clean and green, however I am hoping to report a reporting engine similar to jasperjs on JS.

reporting meaning:

1. defining reports
2. built-in "renderers"
3. entering of chart data in a standardised format
4. building a simple API, allowing for the creation of chart exports

Would appreciate a rough gauge of the difficulty level. And advice if I should propose django as opposed to nodejs.

this is my first job after graduation at college and will take all the help I can get.

thanks for reading.

good reading:

1. [Node vs python for creating RESTful webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513236/node-vs-python-for-creating-restful-webservices)
2. http://www.brandttechnologies.com/papers/121106f_2012141_Using_Node_In_Reporting_System.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a reporting engine similar to Jasper Reports that runs on top of Node.JS, then i'm not aware of any, if you're looking to create it yourself, then i advise you is very difficult and time consuming to write a full reporting engine, but if you really want to do so, you should take a look at Jasper Reports source code, and this project that partially implements [Jasper Reports on PHP](http://www.simit.com.my/?q=PHPJasperXML).

Comment: http://www.brandttechnologies.com/papers/121106f_2012141_Using_Node_In_Reporting_System.pdf

Comment: I am actually looking to do something like it looks easy on paper. interested to try with all the hype on nodejs going about.

Comment: At this point I am tempted to take a leap of faith and jump into nodejs due to 1. asynchronous abilities 2. I get to learn something new. I am only worried about the time required to pick up django and nodejs